# How can i add new item to wordpress sidemenu, with icon on it

Tags: php, wordpress

How can i add new item to wordpress sidemenu, with icon on it?. So far i have done this , but when clicked , it will redirect to another page. i dont want to redirect to new page . but i want to redirect to logout page
i have searched here on stackoverflow . but no answers so far.
here is what i treid, in functions.php file:

```
/*
 *  Logout
 */

add_action('admin_menu', 'logout_menu_item');
function logout_menu_item() {
    add_menu_page('Logout', 'Logout', 'manage_options', 'logout', "wp_logout", 'dashicons-external', 999); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refrence https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/menu.php

```
<?php 

add_action('admin_init', 'logout_menu_item_link');

function logout_menu_item_link() {
    global $menu;
    $menu[9999] = array(__('Logout'), 'read', wp_logout_url(),'','custom-class','custom-id','dashicons-external');

}
```

Comment: Good! A little tip: if the menu item looks misaligned, just add `menu-top` class parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> **Try Like This:**

```
<?php 

add_action('admin_init', 'logout_menu_item_link');

function logout_menu_item_link() {
    global $menu;
    $menu[9999] = array(__('Logout'), 'manage_options', wp_logout_url());
}

?>
```

> example: Add Icons: https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#album

Comment: tried this , but if we do this, there is no icon in leftside

Comment: @georgeB ,  You Can add the Icon , using an global custom css, form the inspect elemet and then add into global css file in settings

Comment: @georgeB Check This For Icon add: https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#album

Comment: whe i checked in inspect element there is no unique class or id for this perticular item. so how can i add the css to it?

Comment: also on the link( developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#album ), `add_menu_page` was described, but it didnt either work.